# Detect browser current "media" mode

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, printing, media

I have a page with some javascript and I don't want this script to run on print preview page / print.
I can disable CSSes with media="screen". How can I detect "print" mode in javascript? I need at least a Chrome solution

Comment: Please make sure to look for identical questions before re-asking.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well u need [jquery](http://jquery.com)

And then a plugin of it name [jmediatype](http://code.google.com/p/jmediatype/)

Then u can get if it is print meada type by :

```
media.print
```