# is there any down pits with using setTimeout() for jQuery "media query" type situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive site. I'm browsing for a way to handle jQuery "media query" changes so to speak.

I got some calculations like height, width ect on some elements and i would need to recalculate those when the media query change, like from 1160px to 980px.

I found a solution that feels like a good one because it should be supported by most browsers (if not all?) but I'm just not sure if there is any performance or any other issues with having a `setTimeout()` running as frequent as this one.

jsfiddle for [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/9X4up/45/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    //code here
}, 100);​
```

maybe there is some other better way using a already made plugin by paulirish or any other crew? Please advice me with your experience on this subject.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries

Comment: yes thats the one i got the idea with the `setInterval()` but it really does not help me to establish a example of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this code to handle jquery "media queries". I took a element that got the size of my media queries (480, 980, 1160) as selectors, usually a wrapper or like in my case the header.

```
var myDivWidth = $('YOUR-SELECTOR').width();
$(window).resize(function () {

    if ($('YOUR-SELECTOR').width() != myDivWidth) {

        //If the media query has been triggered
                myDivWidth = $('YOUR-SELECTOR').width();

        //Your resize logic here                
         }
});
```