# How to use Enquire.Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, enquire.js

**[Enquire.js](http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/)**  is a Javascipt that re-creates CSS media queries for Javascripts.
This means you can wrap your Javascripts in Media Queries. (Just like you would wrap CSS in Media Queries).

I'm not quite sure how to use it. [This tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/) says this:

```
enquire.register("max-width: 960px", function() {
  // put your code here
});
```

However, when I follow that, my code stops working.

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/PnR2w/1/) an example of some Jquery Tabs without Enquire.JS. It works fine.

[Here are](http://jsfiddle.net/ZH25x/2/) the same tabs, but with Enquire.JS added. Now it stops working.

I've experimented with different variations of the code, but none of them work. What am I doing wrong?

I think you might have place the Jquery Tab code in a separate file and then link to that file from within Enquire.Js, but I'm not sure how you would do that. (Although it would be handy to know as I'd imagine it would let you keep your scripts be more reusable).

PS. This is not a criticism of Enquire.Js. I know that the problem lies squarely with my lack of proficiency in Javascript! I did spend a couple of hours searching for a solution, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** enquire.js v2 is now out and the documentation includes [working examples](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#Examples)

I know you asked me on GitHub about better documentation in general, but I came across this question here so thought I'd try to help with the specific problem you're having here as well.

Your original code was as so:

```
enquire.register("max-width: 500px", function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

}).listen(); //note: as of enquire.js v2 listen() has been deprecated
```

There's a few small issues with this which I'll explain now. The most obvious is that you have placed the document ready callback *inside* the match function. Whilst this may actually work perfectly fine, it would be considered better practice to instead have all the enquire code inside the ready callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    enquire.register("max-width: 500px", function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    }).listen(); //note: as of enquire.js v2 listen() has been deprecated

});
```

This is a better approach because you don't have to add a register callback in every match function (if you have more than one handler or more than one query.

The second, more subtle, problem is that your media query is not considered valid. Any [media query feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1) must be surrounded by parentheses. Also you typically want to specify a media device (briefly covered here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#background), usually you would pick `screen` for websites. The media device and media query feature you're testing for are then separated by an `and`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 500px)", function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    }).listen();

}); //note: as of enquire.js v2 listen() has been deprecated
```

That should then be all that is required to fix your code. You can see a completed example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WickyNilliams/3nXce/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I have some follow up questions, but they are a bit awkward to post them in this tiny comment box. Is it okay to post them on the Github thread, or should I post them as a separate Stackoverflow question?

Comment: Depends what type of issue you have really. If it's due to lack of understanding because the documentation isn't clear, feel free to add to the existing issue on github. If it's just a general usage question create a new question here on here, reply to let me know what you do

Comment: Hi Thanks for your kindness. I have posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808691/using-enquire-js-to-switch-between-scripts-according-to-screen-size

Comment: @WickyNilliams I came accross your post because I was first looking for an alternative to CSS regions, your tool is the best one (much better than polyfills wich doasn't work very well on each browsers) and open it opened my mind for much more features. Thanks a lot!