# Using Enquire.JS to switch between scripts according to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, enquire.js

I've made a page that has two different scripts. The script that runs is determined by the screen size. [Enquire.Js](http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/) is used to achieve this.

When the page is viewed on screen bigger than 600px, I want the content to be displayed with jQuery Tabs.
I have made a test model here and it works fine: [Live Page](http://olo.uk.com/itest/desktoponly.html) ||  [JS Fiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/2UbW8/1/)

Although it works, it only works one way. I.e. when the window is resized Enqiurie.js does its 'magic'. But if the window is re-sized again, the 'magic' is not reversed. (in contrast to a CSS media query where re-sizing the window again reverse the media query).

When the page is viewed on a screen smaller than 600px, I want it to be displayed with an iPhone style Nav.
I have made a test model here and it also works fine: [Live Page](http://olo.uk.com/itest/iphoneonly.html) || [JS Fiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ8aC/)
However, again it only works one way.

When I try to combine the two demos (i.e. so it switches between Tabs and iphone style Nav, it doesn't quite work. 
See the test model here: [Live Page](http://olo.uk.com/itest/both.html) || [JS Fiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/JHVDs/2/)

If the browser is more than 600px on load, you have to refresh the window for the tabs to appear.
If you reisze the window from less than 600px to more than 600px, some of the less-than-600px-code seems to persist.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, in my opinion what you're doing wrong is basing the layout on a JavaScript solution and not CSS Media Queries (with appropriate fallback of course).  Note that lots of Android phones cross the 600 pixel boundary when you switch between portrait and landscape view.

Comment: Your problem here is that you are not undoing your changes when a query is *unmatched*. For example, with the tabs, you would call it's destroy method when the query is unmatched `$("#tabs").tabs("destroy")`. Your code for "iphone style" is making changes to DOM that aren't as easily reversible (mainly because they're not packaged in a neat widget like the jQuery UI stuff). Another issue is that you have lots of css classes/ID's in place by default to give the "iphone style". These will, of course, make the tabs look wonky.

Comment: Pointy: Thanks for your reply! I know you can do the tabs in pure CSS, but do you know if it is possible to do the iPhone slider list Navigation in pure css? PS. The 600px is just for this demo.   WickyNilliams: Thanks for your help! Do you know if there is a way to package the iphone nav code into a widget? I know there are several Jquery mobile frameworks. However, none of them seem to offer the navigation as a single line of code (like the tabs). In the mobile frameworks, creating an iphone list style navigation requires several lines of code. Thanks for any help you can offer!