# switch functions based on media queries with Enquire.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, enquire.js

This is really the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808691/using-enquire-js-to-switch-between-scripts-according-to-screen-size) but I'm hoping somebody can answer it more thoroughly.

I'm trying to create a "mobile" and a "full" version of a site using two different js functions. I understand responsive design and I'm doing most of the changes through CSS but the two versions will need to have two different mutually exclusive js functions. [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) allows the use of media queries and they do work well if the browser window is not resized. But if you resize the window from "full" to "mobile", the function full() in my example does not stop running despite my best (probably not very good) efforts below. The alerts are always correct however: "true" for full() and "false" for mobile(), the functions just seem to ignore the if statements.  I'm okay with not using enquire if there's a better option.

**js-decider.js**

```
$(function() {

window['fullEnabled'];
window['mobileEnabled'];

enquire.register("screen and (min-width:680px)", {

match : function() {

 window['fullEnabled'] = true;
 window['mobileEnabled'] = false;
 full();

}

}).register("screen and (max-width:679px)", {

match : function() {

 window['fullEnabled'] = false;
 window['mobileEnabled'] = true;
 mobile();

}

}).listen();

});
```

**full.js**

```
function full() {

    if (window['fullEnabled']==true) {
        alert(window['fullEnabled']);
        // do other stuff
    }

}
```

**mobile.js**

```
function mobile() {

    if (window['mobileEnabled']==true) {
        alert(window['fullEnabled']);
        // do other stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey man, if you create a fiddle I'll have a look at your issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your media queries are causes the issue you have a cross over.

Try this instead:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:679px)", {
    match : function() {
        //small screen
    }
}).register("screen and (min-width:680px)", {
    match : function() {
        //large screen
    }
}).listen();
```