# Enquire.js not working on page load, only works when screen <= 480px

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, enquire.js

So I am using Enquire.js to add and remove bootstrap's pre-defined css classes for my website.
Here is what I have:

Some bootstrap HTML thumbnails:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="thumb thumb col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id ="thumb" class="thumb col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have set up the enquire.js so that the thumbnail sizes resize based on screen size as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $info = $('.thumb');

    enquire.register("(max-width: 480px)", {

    match: function() {      
        $info.removeClass('col-xs-6');
        $info.addClass('col-xs-12');
    },


    unmatch: function() {
         $info.removeClass('col-xs-12');
         $info.addClass('col-xs-6');      
    }

    }).listen();

</script>
```

**Problem:**

The problem I am having is that the enquire.js code **only kicks in once the screen size has been reduced to 480px or less**.

So when the site is first loaded, the resize code won't work until I actually manually resize it down to 480px or lower and then you can see the resizing take place.

You can have a look at the site [here](http://talk.hostoi.com/bootstrap/index)

Comment: Working fine in FF 30 and IE 11 and Chrome 36

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight What exactly have you tested? I have tested in all browsers and its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unmatch function will only work when it goes from a matched state to an unmatched state.

I think you want to use the **setup** function as well. This will run the javascript inside when the handler is called. These are the four main calls from the [enquire.js site](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:45em)", {

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered when a media query matches.
match : function() {},      

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered when the media query transitions 
// *from a matched state to an unmatched state*.
unmatch : function() {},    

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered once, when the handler is registered.
setup : function() {},    

// OPTIONAL, defaults to false
// If set to true, defers execution of the setup function 
// until the first time the media query is matched
deferSetup : true,

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered when handler is unregistered. 
// Place cleanup code here
destroy : function() {}

});
```

Comment: Yes, the setup function is what triggers the handler to start with. This works fine. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might need to have the code inside a document ready. Here using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        var $info = $('.thumb');

        enquire.register("(max-width: 480px)", {

        match: function() {      
            $info.removeClass('col-xs-6');
            $info.addClass('col-xs-12');
        },


        unmatch: function() {
             $info.removeClass('col-xs-12');
             $info.addClass('col-xs-6');      
        }

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work... in fact with this code the enquire.js code doesn't work at all

Comment: Yes but I am using `enquire.js` in this case

Comment: My suggestion requires both. As specified in the answer. My suggestion is based in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12789816/3877639).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and have tried wrapping the code in a `$(document).ready(function() {..}` but still does absolutely nothing

Comment: Which version of enqiure.js are you using? If you use v2, [.listen()is deprecated](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#v2.0.0), just remove it.