# Call external JS file based on "media screen" value

Tags: jquery, html, external, media-queries

I'm trying this but it is not working:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/menu-collapser.js" type="text/javascript" media="media screen and (max-width: 599px)"></script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

//menu-collapser.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.main-navigation li ul').hide();
    $('.main-navigation li').has('ul').click(function() {
        $(this).children().toggle();
    });
});
```

Do you have an idea on how to do this in the right way? The script work if used directly in the header with the  tags.

Answer (score 18):

You can't do that directly using Javascript `<script>` tags. Media queries are used in linked CSS files or inline CSS styles. A basic example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="desktop.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 571px)" href="tablet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 570px)" href="mobile.css"/>
```

Or directly in your stylesheets:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  #mobile {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

However, you can use an external asset loader/media query library to do this ([require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/), [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) and others), In this case, I'm setting an example using [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), as I think it's very effective and doesn't require jQuery by default:

### Full example

**1) Include enquire.js (available [here](https://raw.github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/master/dist/enquire.min.js)):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/enquire.js"></script>
```

**2) Create a load function - to load JS files:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// This loads JS files in the head element
    function loadJS(url)
    {
        // adding the script tag to the head
       var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.src = url;

       // fire the loading
       head.appendChild(script);
    }

</script>
```

**3) Fire enquire.js and listen for media query changes (both on-load and on-resize):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 599px)", {
        match : function() {
            // Load a mobile JS file
            loadJS('mobile.js');
        }
    }).listen();


    enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px)", {
        match : function() {
            // Load a tablet JS file
            loadJS('tablet.js');
            //console.log('tablet loaded');
        }
    }).listen();


    enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 900px)", {
        match : function() {
            // Load a desktop JS file
            loadJS('desktop.js');
            //console.log('desktop loaded');
        }
    }).listen();
</script>
```

### Putting it all together

Using a simple HTML page with enquire.js loaded from an external file:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/enquire.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// This loads JS files in the head element
    function loadJS(url)
    {
        // adding the script tag to the head
       var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.src = url;

       // fire the loading
       head.appendChild(script);
    }

</script>

<style>

    body {
      font-family: arial;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 50pt;
    }

    #mobile {
      display: none;
    }
    #tablet {
      display: none;
    }
    #desktop {
      display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
        #mobile {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px) {
        #tablet {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
        #desktop {
            display: block;
        }
    }   

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="desktop">
        <h1>Desktop</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="tablet">
        <h1>Tablet</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="mobile">
        <h1>Mobile</h1>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 599px)", {
            match : function() {
                // Load a JS file
                loadJS('mobile.js');
            }
        }).listen();


        enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px)", {
            match : function() {
                loadJS('tablet.js');
                //console.log('tablet loaded');
            }
        }).listen();


        enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 900px)", {
            match : function() {
                loadJS('desktop.js');
                //console.log('desktop loaded');
            }
        }).listen();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition to loading JS files, you could create a CSS loader too, which would work in the same way (conditionally), but that defeats the object of using `@media` in CSS. It's worth reading the usage explanations for [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#basics), as it can do a lot more than I've illustrated here.

**Caveat:** Nothing above uses jQuery, but you could take advantage of some of the functions it offers; loading scripts for example - or executing other functions that you need to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your complete explaination. I'm tryin to follow your suggestions but it's not easy for me. Do i have to download require.js/modernizr.js, include them in the head and then use your second code in the body? Because it doesn't seems to work...

Comment: you are amazing, thanks for your help. unfortunatly i can't get it to work! :(
if you are so kind to take a look at my code, i've simplified it and pasted here: http://pastebin.com/HkviLP9H

Comment: @l736k There doesn't seem anything wrong with your code - It works in Chrome/Safari, **but** what does `menu-collapser.js` do!?

Comment: menù collapser contains the jQuery script i've posted in the initial question...it should collapse the subpages of the menù in the mobile version of the theme.
there might be some other problems as the jQuery code i have USED to works if typed directly into the body but now doesn't work anymore...and i can't understand why!
you can see the live site at this URL if you want to have a better idea (try resizing the browser and you'll see the menù that changes under 599px): is.gd/6ju6a1

Comment: actually, i geti it back to work but it ignore the screen dimensions...the script works also if the browser >599px...so in the full width version the menu have troubles...

Comment: would you please check this question, nickhar? it's about the same script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969807/using-enquire-to-load-js-files-loads-the-first-file-only-with-media-queries

Comment: enquire.js version 2.0.0 no longer uses the `listen()` call, for any interested parties.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just load in a script conditionally?

```
(function() {
    if( window.innerWidth > 600 ) {
        var theScript = document.createElement('script');
            theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            theScript.src = 'js/menu-collapser.js';

        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(theScript, s);
    }
})();
```

Or better yet, only execute the code if the window.innerWidth > 600 ? Anyway, there are a lot of solutions you can use.

Answer (score 2):

`media` is not a valid attribute for `<script>`, check it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

So you should detect media types by manually than load the script dynamically.

[There is a plug-in for css media detection in javascript](http://cssmedia.pemor.pl/), you can use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mediatypechecker.js"></script>

$(function() {
    if(IsMediaType('screen') > 0 && parseInt(screen.width) < 599) {
        $.getSscript("js/menu-collapser.js");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to react to later resizing events (e.g. on desktop) as well, you can do it like this:

```
<script>
  moby = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");
  moby.addListener(
    moby=>{
      if(moby.matches){
        document.head.innerHTML+="<script src='wonderfulScreenAffectedScript.js'></script>";
    }
   }
  );
</script>
```