# How to include a JavaScript file when the screen is a certain size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-size

I want to include a file such as foo.js, only when the screen is a certain size.

**For example:**

```
<script>
if (screen.width <= 960)
{
    document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="/foo.js">\x3C/script>'); 
}
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might think of putting the `</script>` at the beginning of `document.write`.  Otherwise you have a script in a script.

Comment: Why not always include the script file and wrap its contents in the conditional?

Comment: Here is a smiliar question with a few different solutions:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823137/call-external-js-file-based-on-media-screen-value][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823137/call-external-js-file-based-on-media-screen-value

Comment: What happens when the screen is resized after it has been loaded? you can't un-include a script file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append the script to the head, don't use `document.write`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (screen.width <= 960) {
       var head    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
       var script  = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.src  = '/foo.js';
       head.appendChild(script);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Can this go at the bottom of your html file with the other scripts?

Comment: @MaxwellLynn  - Yes it can !

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, try this:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 960) {     
    document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="/foo.js">\x3C/script>');
}
```