# JavaScript queries?

Tags: javascript, mobile

There are @media queries for css that use certain stylesheets for certain circumstances, is there a JavaScript equivalent that would load certain JavaScript functions at certain screen widths/landscape/portrait etc. ? I'd like to have all my JavaScript on one document (all internal because I only have one page to work with) but only access certain parts in certain circumstances/devices. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823137/call-external-js-file-based-on-media-screen-value)

Comment: It would help to be more specific, but you can always put tests in any piece of js you create to check the size, or read the current css settings before doing what it does.  If you have different controls hide or appear with different media queries you could change things based on what js is attached to them.

Comment: I'm trying to give single buttons different methods at different screen widths so at one width, it would change the currently displaying sections properties to 'block' and at another width to 'flex' when clicked because by default, these other sections' displays are set to 'none'. I only have one web page to work with, but I'm trying to get it as close to being a 'site' as possible.

Comment: To get it to function the way I want it to (just to take a quick baby step) at max-width : 480px I'd like an alert that says 'your screen is under 480px' and at another, I'd like for an alert to say 'your screen is over 480px' without having both alerts pop up regardless of screen size.