# style tag media attribute equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive

stylesheets can be made to load only for some devices using:

`<link href="big.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)">`

OR

`<style media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"></style>`

Is there an equivalent way to load specific scripts for specific devices?
I cannot modify the script since it is provided by third-party cdn imported using:
`<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>`

Comment: Check for User Agent or screen sizes.

Comment: This questions might be useful [How to load or not a JS script (into the head section) based on screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848465/how-to-load-or-not-a-js-script-into-the-head-section-based-on-screen-resolutio) and [Call external JS file based on “media screen” value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15823281/5533075)