# How do I load jquery mobile only for mobile browsers, but the regular site for desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

So I have an existing desktop html site, but I've created a jquery mobile version. The thing is I'm trying to figure out how to load only the jquery mobile version for mobile phones, but show the desktop version for desktops. I couldn't find anything on the jquery mobile documentation.

Comment: Search for 'redirect mobile browsers.' It's not jQuery specific. Best done with a server-side language such as PHP.

Comment: @Mooseman Thanks! I found a few solutions with the search 'redirect mobile browsers'.

Answer (score 1):

You can essentially do with with jquery using the window width or by triggering it on CSS media query breakpoints. A few references below:

[Triggering jquery with css media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries)

http://www.venveo.com/articles/view/quick-tip-jquery-media-queries

I am however now sure of the ramifications of making it responsive... once jquery mobile kicks in, all bets are off.

You are probably better off calling the jquery mobile on a browser detection rather than a screen breakpoint.