# JavaScript media query to reverse user triggered JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design

The brilliant amateur that I am I decided to make a website responsive. My website has a sidebar and I figured I would use a media query to hide that sidebar and show a button to make the side bar toggle-able. I used jpanelmenu http://jpanelmenu.com/ to do this.

The problem is if you do the following it all breaks apart

1. shrink down browser width to mobile size
2. the sidebar disappears
3. the button to toggle the sidebar appears
4. press the button and the sidebar appears
5. expand the browser window to normal side
6. now I have two fricken sidebars (the one from the jpanel menu) and the original sidebar that has now reappeared because the browser window has grown and my media-query unhides it
7. to top it off the mobile sidebar toggle button has disappeared because we are back to normal width

clearly this won't work, so should I use modernizer and a javascript media query ala [Triggering jquery with css media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries)
to fix it or is there a more elegant solution my amateur mind is not seeing?

Comment: can we have the html structure or a jsfiddle view of your layout...

Comment: see this page on the Foundation CSS responsive framework, follow my steps above, they are victims of the exact same issue... http://www.zurb.com/playground/playground/off-canvas/offcanvas-4.html