# How do I use jQuery to fire different functions while using @media handheld?

Tags: jquery, function, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make my website responsive. My website is essentially all one page and I use a simple jQuery scroll function to navigate to different sections. It works fine for desktop or laptop computers but doesn't really work when you view it on mobile or tablet especially in portrait. So I wrote a jQuery function that turns each section of my website into a tab instead of it scrolling. So for example if you click the "Work" section it appears as if you are going to a different page. What I would ultimately like to do is use both functions the "scroll" on my computer and the "tab" on mobile and tablet. Using @media handheld can I call the "tab" function? Or do I need to create an "if statement that can determine where the website is being accessed from? Below is the code for my tab function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('.tabs a.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active').blur();
        var panel = $this.attr('href');
        $(panel).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    });//end click
    $('.tabs li:first a').click();
}); // end ready
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries

Comment: Not a 100% sure that will work but I will add modernizer to my site and try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia) and there are some libraries which can help you like :

https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaCheck with a fallback which uses `window.resize`

If you want to go further reading some good stuff about that point, than please read [this](http://viget.com/inspire/managing-javascript-on-responsive-websites) article, as it describes lot of stuff from this nature.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to write the if statement in this case though? Do I simply put each function in a different file and tell it to load one if it meets requirement X and load the other if it meets requirement Y?

Comment: You can only pass media queries and if they are fired, than the function is executed.