# How do I turn off jquery cycle 2 pager plugin using CSS?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Looking to disable the pager while leaving the slide show running for tablets & mobile devices.

Basically I need a way to turn off the pager in CSS.

Thank you

Comment: turn a jquery plugin off in css? why not use jquery to turn the jquery plugin off.. at least that's possible.

Comment: Interesting answer really only poses another question.

Comment: So how would that be done automatically when the form is in the tablet size & phone size ?

Comment: see if this helps (using jquery based on a media query) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries?rq=1

Comment: This does help greatly thank you. I do need to ask where we would what value we would enter into the jcycle code and where to turn it off, or do we merely hide it?

Comment: according to the docs `$('#slideshow').cycle('stop');` would stop the slideshow, `$('#slideshow').cycle('destroy');` would stop and unbind all events, if stop doesn't do the desired effect you could simply hide the div, i imagine even `$('#slideshow').hide();` would work

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your time. I am just looking to stop the pager in the smaller screens however I do believe the code you have given will get me there. Thank you again. Have a great week.