# Function should only be executed when media query is true

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I’m looking for a way to only fire a jQuery function when a certain media query is true.

The example below shows a slide down nav which should be expanded when the viewport is wider than 500px. If the viewport is less, the nav should be hidden and expandable by clicking on the link.

Here’s a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qjh3p/1/

HTML

```
<a id="mobile-menu">Slide Down</a>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    display: block;
}


@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var mobile = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches;

  if (mobile) {

      $("#mobile-menu").click(function() {
          $("nav").slideToggle( "500" );
      });

      $("nav ul li a").click(function() {
          $("nav").slideToggle( "500" );
      });

  }

});



$(document).resize(function () {

  var mobile = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches;

  if (mobile) {

      $("#mobile-menu").click(function() {
          $("nav").slideToggle( "500" );
      });

      $("nav ul li a").click(function() {
          $("nav").slideToggle( "500" );
      });

  }

});
```

Comment: try changing .slideToggle to simply .toggle OR change the "500" to "slow" OR change the string "500" to the number 500.

Comment: 500 is a number, not a string. What about `.slideToggle(500)`?

Comment: The script itself works but I have a problem with setting the media queries (when the viewport is less than 500px when the page loads).

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the media queries?

Comment: It doesn’t work on resize: As I mentioned the script works when the page is loaded with a viewport less than 500px – but it then also works when the viewport is wider than 500px. Otherwise it the script doesn’t work when the page is loaded with a viewport wider than 500px and is than resized to a viewport less than 500px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggering jquery with css media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries)