# Bootstrap carousel change disposition on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was attempting to make a carousel with partial preview of next/prev slides with bootstrap 4 but without sucess.. Now with version 3.3.7 I got it.
But now I have new issues, I want that the slides make 100% (meanwhile 33% of desktop) on mobile and still sliding.

I'm following this [example](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RKavve)

On desktop (Its ok!):
[image]

On mobile:
[image]

I wish it be this way on mobile:
[image]

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="carousel-1" data-interval="false" class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="img-resposnive" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="img-resposnive" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="img-resposnive" />
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="" />
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="" />
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="" />
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="" />
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="https://guiadacozinha.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bolo-cenoura-festa.jpg" class="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#carousel-1" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  <a href="#carousel-1" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
```

SCSS CODE

```
    .multi-item-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.multi-item-carousel img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.left,
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 25%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner {
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.item__third {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .item__third {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item > img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
            min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Javascript code:

```
jQuery('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
      var next = jQuery(this).next();
      if (!next.length) next = jQuery(this).siblings(':first');
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo(jQuery(this));
    });
    jQuery('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
      var prev = jQuery(this).prev();
      if (!prev.length) prev = jQuery(this).siblings(':last');
      prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo(jQuery(this));
    });
```

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: I think it would help if you made a code pen of your own code

Comment: @jwebb Im following the example I mentioned (https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RKavve), only changed the images at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Image seems to be behind the navbar. Try adding height to the nav. That should help.

If you want to totally change the carousel look you can add a second carousel ([example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators)) and display it on small device using @media

Comment: Hello Apacz, thanks for your help. I want that shows only one image each slide on mobile, meanwhile desktop shows 3 (part of next and prev images)... Theres any way or I have to make 2 carousels?

Comment: You can try edit your carousel triggering jQuery [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461300/triggering-jquery-with-css-media-queries/6461561#6461561)